# zend form collection

Tags: forms, zend-framework, zend-form

How I can create for with one to many relations? For example I have an Object and him have relations to many images?
I usually use symfony and it have form [collection type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html). Maybe Zend have something like that?

UPDATE:
I want create this form using Zend_Form.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you referring to forms or database tables with a one to many relation?

Comment: @Luke I want create this form using Zend_Form.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are asking. Can you give an example? If you have an object with a property set to an array, you can use a foreach loop to go through the array and dynamically add form elements inside the loop. Not sure if this answers your question though. Are you asking how to get the array from the database, or how to populate the form?

Comment: I'm not sure, but [sub forms](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.subforms) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: You need to rethink how you're going to try and do things in ZF. Symfony appears far more black box like then ZF is. What your link appears to be describing is a form model class the incorporates what seems to be a mapper. You can do all of this in ZF, but you have to do it, ZF won't presume to do it for you.

Comment: @RockyFord I finished this task, with usage subforms and ElementsBelongTo. But why method setElementsBelongTo not working with file type field?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think you can assign a file element to an array with ElementBelongsTo because of the way the element receives(upload) the file(s).

Comment: If you have solved this, please post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 2 forms classes. First form is the main form and the second form, it is the i want add dynamic. In controller I check how many new elements appeared to form

```
count($request->getParam('subForm'))
```

previously using

```
$subForm->setElementsBelongTo('subForm')
```

and add new subforms in controller and save it.